# Using Integrals to find f(x).

Tags: calculus

Find $f (t)$ from the information given

$f '(t) = 1 + t^2j$ and $f (0) = j − k.$

What I have tried so far is to take the integral of $f'(t) = 1+t^2$

$∫ 1+t^2 dx$

$= 2t + C$

Then

$f(0) = 2(0) = 0$

Unfortunately this is not the answer. I would like to know what steps to perform to acquire the right result.

Comment: **HINT**: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(1+t^2)\neq \int\,(1+t^2)\;\mathrm{d}t$

In addition, you should always close off your integrals with an "infinitesimal":
$\mathrm{d}t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given: $f '(t) = 1 + t^2j$ and $f (0) = j − k.$

$$f(t) = a+t+\frac{j}{3}t^3$$

Using $f (0) = j − k$ results in

$$a = j-k$$

Hence $$f(t)=j-k+t+\frac{j}{3}t^3$$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int (1+t^2 j) dt=t+\frac{t^3}{3}j+c$$

$$f(0)=j-k \Rightarrow c=j-k$$

So we deduce that $f(t)=y+\frac{j}{3} t^3+(j-k)$